# FactType.getFields return no fields drools KIE

Tags: eclipse, maven, drools, kie, kie-workbench

I have created a fact type( CustomerFact ) with two fact fields(age and bonus) . A sample rule is also created using workbench. Now, I want to inject some test values and check whether the rules are getting fired. I used Eclipse IDE.

I am able to retrieve package name and the rule created in workbench in my java code. However, I am enable to get any fact fields. GetFields always returns an empty list whereas it should have returned 2 fields. Is there any alternative to this? I just want to set the field of the fact type and see whether the rules are getting fired. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
package org.demo.cityproject;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class CustomerFact implements java.io.Serializable
{

   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @org.kie.api.definition.type.Key
   private int age;
   @org.kie.api.definition.type.Key
   private int bonus;

   public CustomerFact()
   {
   }

   public int getAge()
   {
      return this.age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age)
   {
      this.age = age;
   }

   public int getBonus()
   {
      return this.bonus;
   }

   public void setBonus(int bonus)
   {
      this.bonus = bonus;
   }

   public CustomerFact(int age, int bonus)
   {
      this.age = age;
      this.bonus = bonus;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o)
   {
      if (this == o)
         return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
         return false;
      org.demo.cityproject.CustomerFact that = (org.demo.cityproject.CustomerFact) o;
      if (age != that.age)
         return false;
      if (bonus != that.bonus)
         return false;
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode()
   {
      int result = 17;
      result = 31 * result + age;
      result = 31 * result + bonus;
      return result;
   }

}
```

### Test Code

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String url = "http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-jboss-as7/maven2/Project1/org/demo/CityProject/1.0/CityProject-1.0.jar";
        ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("org.demo", "CityProject", "LATEST");
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        kieServices.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
        KieScanner kieScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
        kieScanner.scanNow();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("kieContainer.getKieBaseNames() "+kieContainer.getKieBaseNames());

        KieSession newKieSession =kieContainer.newKieSession("session1");
        KieBase lKieBase=newKieSession.getKieBase();
        System.out.println("lPackage "+lKieBase.getKiePackages());
        KiePackage lPackage=lKieBase.getKiePackage("org.demo.cityproject");
        System.out.println("lPackage FactTypes: "+lPackage.getFactTypes());
        for(FactType lFact:lPackage.getFactTypes())
        {
            System.out.println("lFacts: "+lFact.getName());
            System.out.println("lFacts Fields: "+lFact.getFields());

        }
}
```

### Console o/p in eclipse

```
22:58:28.998 [main] DEBUG o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId org.demo:CityProject:LATEST was not in cache, checking maven repository
22:58:37.430 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:37.743 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:39.455 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:39.503 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for org.demo:CityProject/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
22:58:39.503 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for org.demo:CityProject/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
22:58:39.503 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for org.demo:CityProject/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
22:58:41.744 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=32, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=15}
22:58:42.230 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:42.230 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:42.246 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=0, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=0, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=0}
22:58:47.596 [main] INFO  o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added: ZipKieModule[releaseId=org.demo:CityProject:1.0,file=C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\org\demo\CityProject\1.0\CityProject-1.0.jar]
22:58:47.957 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:47.957 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:47.957 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:48.426 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:48.442 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:48.457 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
22:58:48.457 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for org.demo:CityProject/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
22:58:48.457 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for org.demo:CityProject/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
22:58:48.457 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultUpdateCheckManager - Skipped remote request for org.demo:CityProject/maven-metadata.xml, locally installed metadata up-to-date.
kieContainer.getKieBaseNames() [KnowledgeBaseALL]
22:58:50.532 [main] DEBUG o.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl - Starting Engine in PHREAK mode
lPackage [[Package name=org.demo.cityproject]]
lPackage FactTypes: [ClassDefinition{className='org.demo.cityproject.CustomerFact', superClass='java.lang.Object', interfaces=[java.io.Serializable], definedClass=class org.demo.cityproject.CustomerFact, traitable=null, abstract=false, fields={}, annotations=null}]
lFacts: org.demo.cityproject.CustomerFact
**lFacts Fields: []**
```

As you can see in the output fact field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The - rather disappointing - situation is that there are two or even three kinds of FactTypes:

1. Fact types defined by a declare statement in a DRL file
2. Fact types resulting from Java classes and imported explicitly or implicitly
3. JDK types used as fact types

Method getFactTypes does not return #3. Method getFields returns an empty list for #2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer. Such fields can be invoked by reflection.
Here is how the rules get triggered

```
    for(FactType lFct:lusedpackage.getFactTypes())
    {
        // System.out.println("Customer class "+lFct.getFactClass());
        **Constructor constructor=lFct.getFactClass().getConstructor(String.class,java.math.BigInteger.class);**
        **Object s1=constructor.newInstance(lcity,lcustomerID);**

        //System.out.println("constructor "+constructor);
        //System.out.println("Object "+s1);

        **Method lCustID=lFct.getFactClass().getMethod("getCustomerID");**
        System.out.println("*************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Customer value before firing the rule: "+ lCustID.invoke(s1));
        **Method setCity  = lFct.getFactClass().getMethod("getCity");** 

        System.out.println("City value before firing the rule: "+ setCity.invoke(s1));          
        //System.out.println("method "+lCustID);
        System.out.println("*************************************************************");
        newKieSession.insert(s1);
        newKieSession.fireAllRules();

        System.out.println("Customer value after firing the rule: "+ **lCustID.invoke(s1)**);
        System.out.println("City value after firing the rule: "+ setCity.invoke(s1));
        System.out.println("*************************************************************");                

    }
```